# Best way to filter Symfony Form CollectionType

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Brief introduction to my entities:

I have two enities. "User" and "Timekeepings". A "User" can have many "Timekeepings".

I want to create a form where a user can edit his timekeepings on a per day basis. So i have to filter the Timekeepings by day. What is the best approach to do this?

I could add a OneToMany relationship in my "User" entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Timekeeping::class, mappedBy="user")
 */
private $timekeepings;
```

And then filter those in my FormType, which im not quite sure how to do. But if i go this way Doctrine will fetch all "Timekeepings" for that user. I would like to the filtering on database level if possible, so only the "Timekeepings" im interested are beeing fetched from the database. For example todays date.

Another solution i thought of is by adding a non mapped field in my FormType and fill it manually.

```
$builder->add('timekeepings', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => TimekeepingType::class,
    'mapped' => false,
])
```

I could use a repository to get the Timekeepings of interest. But im not sure how to assign them to my form "timekeepings". And later retrieve them to save changes to the database.

EDIT: Alexandre suggested to use query_builder, which i initially thought of as well, but unfortunetly there is no query_builder for CollectionType

Comment: Is the user the user logged in or it can be any other user ?

Comment: EntityType has an option query_builder where you can edit the query (to find the options). on the other side you probably need some virtual field ono your user entity that carefully handles the timekeepings so you don't lose past/future timekeepings, or a really good data mapper in the form. so perhaps using the unmapped variant might actually be easier/safer overall? ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony form query\_buider and entity repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676773/symfony-form-query-buider-and-entity-repository)

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant I did read about query_builder, but ditched it, because CollectionType does not support it. Can you give me an example on how to set this up in the FormType?

Comment: @DylanKas its currently the logged in user, but in the future admins should be allowed to edit someone else’s timekeepings

Comment: @Jakumi Aren't EntityType only for choice fields?

Comment: you're right, you're gonna need the collectiontype. but the criteria is a bit of a nuissance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is how i solved it:

In my controller i fetch the timekeepings of interest from my repository and pass them forward to my form via form options.

```
$timekeepingsProject = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(TimekeepingProject::class)
    ->findByUserAndYearAndMonthAndDay($user, $year, $month, $day);

$form = $this->createForm(TimekeepingUserType::class, $timekeepingUser, [
    'timekeepingsProject' => $timekeepingsProject,
]);
```

In my form i then add an unmapped field of this type. The data of the field then gets filled with the supplied option in a 'POST_SET_DATA' FormEvent:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // omitted fields...
        ->add('timekeepingsProject', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => TimekeepingProjectType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => false,
        ]);
    
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use($options) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->get('timekeepingsProject')->setData($options['timekeepingsProject']);
    });
}
```

Make sure the option is set as required in the form:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired('timekeepingsProject');
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => TimekeepingUser::class,
    ]);
}
```

Finally my controller handles persisting/removing the timekeepingsProject object to the database. This has to be done because the field is marked as unmapped and thus gets not automatically saved to the database.
Unmapped fields can be accessed like this:

```
$form['timekeepingsProject']->getData()
```